# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't find dependent libraries only during debugging

Tags: java, maven, rxtx, virtual-serial-port

I'm working on studens project, which will need to read data send from AtMega via USB (using virtual serial port). To access serial port I'm using NeuronRobotics' nrjavaserial (https://github.com/NeuronRobotics/nrjavaserial), which is a fork of RXTX. To manage my dependencies I'm using maven. Here's what I get when I run `CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();` (or whichever static `CommPortIdentifier` function):

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\Grześ\AppData\Local\Temp\libNRJavaSerial_Grze?_0\libNRJavaSerial.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1938)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1821)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
    at gnu.io.NativeResource.loadResource(NativeResource.java:142)
    at gnu.io.NativeResource.inJarLoad(NativeResource.java:40)
    at gnu.io.NativeResource.loadLib(NativeResource.java:60)
    at gnu.io.NativeResource.load(NativeResource.java:28)
    at gnu.io.SerialManager.<init>(SerialManager.java:10)
    at gnu.io.SerialManager.getInstance(SerialManager.java:16)
    at gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver.<clinit>(RXTXCommDriver.java:87)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier.<clinit>(CommPortIdentifier.java:109)
    at pl.edu.pwr.aerospace.enginebench.serial.SerialCommunicator.getAvaliablePorts(SerialCommunicator.java:34)
    at pl.edu.pwr.aerospace.enginebench.cli.Main.connectCommunicator(Main.java:35)
    at pl.edu.pwr.aerospace.enginebench.cli.Main.main(Main.java:21)
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\Grześ\AppData\Local\Temp\libNRJavaSerial_Grze?_0\libNRJavaSerial.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1938)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1821)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
    at gnu.io.NativeResource.loadResource(NativeResource.java:142)
    at gnu.io.NativeResource.inJarLoad(NativeResource.java:40)
    at gnu.io.NativeResource.loadLib(NativeResource.java:60)
    at gnu.io.NativeResource.load(NativeResource.java:28)
    at gnu.io.SerialManager.<init>(SerialManager.java:10)
    at gnu.io.SerialManager.getInstance(SerialManager.java:16)
    at gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver.<clinit>(RXTXCommDriver.java:87)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier.<clinit>(CommPortIdentifier.java:109)
    at pl.edu.pwr.aerospace.enginebench.serial.SerialCommunicator.getAvaliablePorts(SerialCommunicator.java:34)
    at pl.edu.pwr.aerospace.enginebench.cli.Main.connectCommunicator(Main.java:35)
    at pl.edu.pwr.aerospace.enginebench.cli.Main.main(Main.java:21)
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError thrown while loading gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver thrown while loading gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver
```

Here are my dependencies:

```
<dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.neuronrobotics</groupId>
            <artifactId>nrjavaserial</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Strangly, this only happens during debugging, when I run program normally it works like charm. Any ideas why?

I found that people had similar problems with other libraries, however solutions for all of them was to move DLLs or update classpath, but as I'm using maven I suspect in this case the solution will be different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix my problem. The root cause of this problem, was my username - "Grześ", which contains non-standard character 'ś'. As you may see in the first line of exception info:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\Grześ\AppData\Local\Temp\libNRJavaSerial_Grze?_0\libNRJavaSerial.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
```

The path contains question mark in place of this character. Changing my username in Windows properties fixed this issue